# Allow mobile access to an InfoPath form on a forms server/sharepoint instance

Tags: sharepoint, windows-mobile, infopath, virtual-pc

Before I begin asking this question I will have to warn you that I know next to nothing about SharePoint and I'm basically learning as I go along.

Here's where I am right now:

- I have a virtual pc with an instance of SharePoint and windows server 2003 running on it
- I have managed to get a network adaptor set up so I can access the SharePoint instance via a web browser in the host.
- I have created and published a InfoPath form to the SharePoint instance and I can view the form in a browser from my host machine.

So far everything is great, the only issue is that in order to view the SharePoint Instance or InfoPaths form in the browser I have to first login as the virtual PCs administrator. Now what I want to do is view the same InfoPath form in a mobile device.

Here's what I have done next:

- On my host machine I created a Windows CE 3.5 application
- in which I added a web browser control and pointed it at the hosted InfoPath form on the SharePoint instance.

Now when I run the application in a mobile emulator I get a connection error, though I do not get this error if I point the control to google, or some other site.

I now have the distinct feeling that the reason for this is that as I mentioned to access the form I needed to login using windows authentication. I tried changing the web application in IIS to allow anonymous access and not require windows authentication. While this worked the SharePoint site stated "Not authorized" so now I gather that SharePoint builds on top of windows authentication to control access to its functionality.

So finally, after all that here's my actual questions:

- How do I grant access in SharePoint to specific bits of functionality for specific windows users?
- For a mobile device that is not a user on the same network as the SharePoint instance how do I give it access to view the InfoPath form?

I know my questions are a little rambled but one bit issue I have with all this is I am really not sure what to ask, or how to word it.  Hopefully someone has grasped what I am trying to do and help out.

To summarize: I basically want to have an emulated mobile device (on the host) access an InfoPath form served by SharePoint/Forms Server on a virtual PC image.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change authentication to SharePoint never do so by changing settings in IIS directly but go to Central Administration, Application Management, Authentication Providers. There you can set it up to use basic authentication, Forms Auth or Anonymous access.. whatever works for you.

Forms Services may have further challenges but this should at least get you a login.